# Saleor migration faild

Tags: django, saleor

I tried to install Saleor but during 
./manage.py migrate
i get

i made superuser but it doesn't work.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/operations.py", line 19, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS %s" % schema_editor.quote_name(self.name))
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 133, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in **exit**
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/honza/projects/saleor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied to create extension "hstore"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.

Answer (score 0):

solutin is > sudo -i -u postgres; ALTER USER saleor_user WITH SUPERUSER